# How do I get divided 6 columns equal 100%?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with dividing in SQL Server.

I am dividing 100/6.00. And it gives me 16.67, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67

Which is 100.02 at the end.

Is there a way to divide 100/6.00 and get 16.66, 16.66, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67 as a result?

I don't look for solution like iif(final sum>100) then . Is there other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to divide only 100 / 6, then just hard code values you are expecting

Comment: The result of `100/6.00`  is `16.666666` so you can sum the values and round to the result to 2 decimals: `SELECT ROUND((100/6.00)+(100/6.00)+(100/6.00)+(100/6.00)+(100/6.00)+(100/6.00),2);`

Comment: Okay that works but I don't need 100 as a final result. I need 16.66 and 16.67 as a result.

Comment: The usual solution is to present results with a disclaimer that totals may not sum to 100% due to rounding. Other approaches suffer from problems with determinism (is the same row getting rounded the same way every time?) and inaccuracies when combining results from different sets (adding 6 16.66 numbers together will not get to 100). If you want this anyway, the simplest approach is to implement division as repeated subtraction (exactly how depends on your query). SQL Server has no native way of "fudging" results like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exact division, then the general answer here is to use an exact type, such as `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`.  Consider:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT CAST(100.0 AS NUMERIC(10, 2)) AS num
)

SELECT num / 6 AS output       -- output is 16.666666
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Yes, but when I will Convert that into a Numeric(10,2) again I will get 16.67 which is not what I expect. When I use the same type then I will finally anyway get 16.67 x6.

Comment: Then the type you use for the intermediate steps needs to have enough precision to avoid this rounding error problem.

Answer (score 1):

...test

```
declare @amount decimal(9,4) = 100;
declare @den decimal(9,4) = 6.00;
declare @dp tinyint = 2; --decimal points for rounding

select val as colid, 
round(@amount/ceiling(@den), @dp,1) +
case when val <= power(10, @dp) * ((@amount- ceiling(@den) * round(@amount/ceiling(@den), @dp,1))%ceiling(@den)) then power(10.0000000000, -@dp) 
else 0.00000 end

from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) as v(val) --max denominator:10
where val <= ceiling(@den);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this somehow help you?

```
DECLARE @counter numeric(5,2) 
DECLARE @row int
DECLARE @number numeric(2,1)
SET @counter= 100
SET @number = 6.0
SET @row = 1
while @counter != 0
BEGIN
    select @counter,@number,@row,@counter/@number
    set @counter = @counter - @counter/@number 
    set @number = @number - 1
    set @row = @row + 1
END
```